# What are these holes for on this European travel adaptor?

Tags: europe, electronic-items, power, gear

I have a standard European travel adaptor. What are the two circled holes on the top and bottom for?

[image]

Answer (score 47, accepted):

All the middle holes are there for accepting various types of **ground (earth) pins**.

Specifically, the top two holes are there for British plugs (BS 546, BS 1363), while the bottom two are there for Brazilian, Danish and Swiss plugs.  As always, Wikipedia has the gory details:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AC_power_plugs_and_sockets

Comment: The lower part of the upper hope looks like it would accept a US plug.

Comment: Or the upper hole, rather.  A grounded US plug is NEMA 5-15P.  The ungrounded analog of that plug (NEMA 1-15P) lacks the pin that would go into the hole in question, but the blades would fit into the inner part of the outer holes on the bottom of the image.

Comment: If this adapter accepts a Danish grounded plug, the ground pin would surely go in one of the _top_ two holes, probably the topmost.

Comment: It's not entirely accurate to decribe BS546 plugs as "British". Obviously, it is a British standard but these plugs have been obsolete in the UK for decades. A friend of mine had to use them in a university hall of residence 25 years ago and they were staggeringly anachronistic even then. They are used in various other countries, though.

Comment: @DavidRicherby the 2A version is still used on lighting circuits and the 5A and 15A for stage lighting (at least dumb incandescent lamps) in the UK.  But as regards travel, you're right that they're more common in Commonwealth countries

Comment: The bottom two holes look like they are for Italian and Swiss plugs. The ground pin on a Danish plug would go in one of the top holes. (I have lived in both Denmark and Switzerland, so I am quite familiar with those plugs.)

Comment: @DavidRicherby I had a house with a modern installation of BS546 sockets.  I'm pretty sure that using another form of socket on the circuit would have been contrary to Regs. (They were for lighting sockets: the lighting was from plug-in lamps, and power to the sockets were controlled by a light-switch on the wall.  The switches aren't rated for 13A, so you need a different socket to prevent someone plugging an iron in.)

Comment: @MartinBonner OK. But it's _very_ unusual to have plug-in lamps controlled by the light switches. Most people who live in the UK will have never seen one of these sockets.

Comment: I bet most people have seen them, younger people just won't recognise them.

Answer (score 51):

Those circled holes will be for various plug style's grounds, however --

## That is not a standard socket.

### That is *entirely an invention of the Chinese junk sellers*.

It has not been approved by any competent testing laboratory, and it definitely never will. This type of socket is simply trying to adapt too many kinds of plugs, at the expense of safety, and it would not be able to be listed even if it was made by a competent builder. As such, the junk sellers *don't even try* to make a safe product. Hence the "for export only" sticker: export it to a jurisdiction we're not responsible for.

Use a listed adapter made for your specific plug-socket pair.

Note that  UL, CSA, TUV, SGS, NTL, ETL etc. are marks of reputable testing agencies. **CE is not a testing agency**, *nor is it reputable, as it allows manufacturers to self-test and self-certify, which turns the mark into “Chinese Excrement.” Relevant to electrical since so most of the world harmonizes to rules like US NEC, which require electrical equipment to be certified by a [recognized testing lab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nationally_Recognized_Testing_Laboratory). CE won't ever be one, for obvious reasons.*

[Hazards of cheapie multi-plug adapter by Big Clive](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=ESIzuV6kdWY)

[John Ward](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=jUu8a6MP0iI) on these… And [his teardown](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=VcNwb0X9Nic).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88363/discussion-on-answer-by-harper-what-are-these-holes-for-on-this-travel-adaptor).

Comment: This may be or not be an answer to the question. Your mods have decided it is worth keeping it here.

Comment: There are adaptors that have exactly this same pattern (I have a few) that are produced by reputable manufacturers. If properly constructed there is no reason for these adaptors to be unsafe.

Comment: @KristvanBesien  Do they in fact have a UL listing, or non-faked listing from other competent [recognized testing lab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nationally_Recognized_Testing_Laboratory)?  I would be thrilled to see that, because it would be a new one by me.  AFAIK there are reasons it is impracticable to create multi-adapters that are safe, e.g. allowing so many pin shapes makes it unlikely to have enough contact area on any one of them.

Comment: Afaict the whole "nationally recognised testing lab" thing is a US thing. The EU relies on manufacturer self-certification for electrical safety :/

Comment: @PeterGreen they rely on manufacturer **or importer** self-certification.  The vast, vast majority of importers are scofflaws because they direct order from AliExpress, eBay or Amazon Marketplace, and completely disregard the law.  People often think "easy to evade" and "not required" are the same, but if that only applies if the authorities don't have to clean up an accident.

Comment: Afaict at least one reputable brand does make make "lots of stuff to schuko" adapters, but I notice the design is very different from the OPs adapter, with a lot more holes, each of which serves only one or two styles of pin. https://docs-emea.rs-online.com/webdocs/1561/0900766b81561375.pdf

Answer (score 12):

Your adapter is designed to acept a wide range of plug types, unfortunately this also tends to mean it accepts none of them well. The "for export only" label doesn't inspire confidence either. That basically means it is shoddy enough that even the country it was made in doesn't consider it safe.

The holes you have circled in red are to accept the earth/ground pins of the aforementioned wide variety of different plug types. Exactly what is hard to tell from the photo but I'm pretty sure at least UK, US and Australian plugs are supported by that hole combination.

Depending on just how crappy the adapter in question is you may or may not find it actually provides an earth connection between the Earth contacts on the Schuko style plug and the earth pin holes in the socket.

Comment: proper British sockets have a mechanical lock that prevents anything from being inserted into the live and neutral before the (longer) grounding prong makes contact. this is probably absent here too.

Comment: @dlatikay Of course it's absent - otherwise US, EU and other plugs wouldn't activate the shutters.

Comment: The plug into the outlet side of the adapter does not have an earth ground prong, so this is definitely circumventing grounding. Plugging a device with a grounded plug into a non-grounded outlet is always unsafe, regardless of adapter quality.

Comment: Schuko style plugs don't use a pin for earthing, they use side contacts. Those side contacts appear to be present on the OPs adapter, whether they are actually connected properly is another matter of course.

Comment: This would *not* suit Australian plugs.  The power and neutral in Australian plugs are flat and at an angle.  This adapter doesn't look it supports that geometry.  And that is without going on about how bad the earth hole looks like.

Comment: @PeterM - I'm pretty sure that it's the angle of the picture that makes those holes look too small/tight to accept the angled Australian plug prongs. FWIW I recall when travelling in Nepal using one that looked just like that to charge my phone (with unearthed AU plug). Even when I had it in my hand, I wasn't sure it would work (not to mention the questionable quality). But sure enough, the prongs fit and the phone charged (I assume the earth would too). Not what you'd call a secure fit though...

Comment: They probably fit the Australian pins well enough. The Chinese similar angled pins in some of their plugs, but the dimensions are very slightly different.

Comment: I think you'll find, for what it's worth, that that particular adapter does accept Australian and Chinese plugs with angled live and neutral pins.

Comment: @trognanders The French CEE 7/5 doesn't have a grounding pin on the plug either, the ground pin is on the wall socket and the pin receptacle is on the appliance plug. Schuko and French can be merged into one, CEE 7/7.

Comment: @user71659 That is interesting. This adapter certainly does seem to have a groove on the side for grounding.

Answer (score 3):

Various grounding pins.

Check [Wikipedia on plugs and sockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AC_power_plugs_and_sockets), to see the variation.

I guess it makes a lot of sense to place the holes similar to what people are used to, and as far as I remember from that list (it's been a while since I spend hours reading through it), all plugs have the grounding pin placed symmetrically in relation to the live pins. And that has resulted in that layout.